# Утечка памяти при изменении координат элемента

Tags: javascript, dom, события, memory

Чем дольше пользователь перемещает курсор внутри элемента *area*, тем больше памяти занимает вкладка.

Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?

```js
area.onmouseenter = function() {
  container.style.display = 'block'
}

area.onmousemove = function(e) {
  container.style.top = e.clientY + 10 + 'px'
  container.style.left = e.clientX + 10 + 'px'
}

area.onmouseout = function() {
  container.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#area {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас не происходит утечка памяти, если запустить profiling, можно увидеть, что браузер сам очищает память.

Когда вы устанавливаете новое css свойство для элемента, происходят самые тяжелые операции для браузера layout, paint, composite layers.

Соответственно растет расход памяти/процессора, подробнее можно прочитать по [ссылке](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=ru).

Но возможно, у Вас есть проблемы в других участках кода, необходимо смотреть все.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все работает нормально, это **не** утечка памяти.
По каждой перемещении курсора в *аrea* работает *onmousemove* который считает координаты курсора и память заполняется, к сожелению , насколько я знаю от этого избежать нелья.
А после выхода с *аrea* работает *onmouseout* и только в это время ГК(Garbage collector) очищается память. 
Вот пример на [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_dom).